# autocomplete search bar using google API?

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, ios7, google-api, xcode5

i am the fresher in ios and i want to make the autocomplete search bar using google API... please tell me how can i make it ... only autocomplete search bar using google API ..

i used this following url ,, but how to complete with search bar ...

```
- (NSString *)description
{
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Query URL: %@", [self googleURLString]];
}


- (NSString *)googleURLString
{
   NSMutableString *url = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&sensor=%@&key=%@",
                        [self.input stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                        SPBooleanStringForBool(self.sensor), self.key];

if (self.offset != NSNotFound) {
    [url appendFormat:@"&offset=%u", self.offset];
}
if (self.location.latitude != -1) {
    [url appendFormat:@"&location=%f,%f", self.location.latitude, self.location.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
if (self.radius != NSNotFound) {
    [url appendFormat:@"&radius=%f", self.radius];
}
if (self.language) {
    [url appendFormat:@"&language=%@", self.language];
}

return url;
}
```

Comment: please anyone given me an answer of this question ....

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

It's an objective-c wrapper for the Google Places Autocomplete API.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you ... but i used it .... but it not search the detail places .... gives me an error domainError 8... when i trying to search detail query ....

Comment: i think you used this code so you have the better solution for my problem.... 

please tell me ..

Comment: I also getting problem, "didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 “The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)” ....

Comment: you have any solution ???? Or you will get solution from other please answer my above question ... 

thank you...

Comment: i have found on google but didn't get proper answer. If you will get then answered me ...

Comment: SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete work well but  only give 5 result each time? is posible to configure to have more results ?